# Error Estimation in Symplectic Numerical Algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have devised a numerical algorithm that solves an equation of type

$$\dot{A} = f(A) \, ,$$

where $A$ is always a symplectic matrix. My algorithm respects this in the sense that, for all $A$ obtained numerically, we have

$$A^T J A = J \quad \text{and, as a consequence,} \quad \det(A) = 1 \, ,$$

where $J$ is the symplectic matrix. Since my algorithm always generates symplectic matrices and there are no exact solutions available for comparison, how can I estimate its error? Other routines that solve this equation do not provide symplectic solutions and deviations are usually searched for using how much they deviate from symplecticity, which is not applicable in my case.

Comment: If you can compute trajectories using different timesteps $h$, then it is very likely that Richardson extrapolation can be used to estimate the error. Moreover, it is possible to determine when the error estimates are reliable. There is much to say on this subject, but you will need to compute trajectories using time steps $h_j = 2^{-j} h_0$ for a modest range of $j=0,1,2,\dotsc$.

Comment: Are you looking for an _a priori_ or _a posteriori_ error estimates, forward or backward?

Comment: You can still use a standard solver to get a reference solution. Then the symplecticity might be violated by some error of scale $10^{-12}$ while the actual error is of, again for example, scale $10^{-6}$, which still gives you a valid error estimate. This only becomes invalid if these two error scales start to match.

Comment: @CarlChristian As far as I know there's no problem using such time steps. I'm currently reading about Richardson extrapolation in Wikipedia.

Comment: @eepperly16 As far as I know, the forward error would require me to define a truth value and use it was a comparison. I don't want to do that, since I can't know how good my calculations are (examples for simple exact systems can be misleading). That would point me in the direction of backward error.

Comment: @LutzL That's the problem... My solutions are obtained as products of symplectic matrices. Symplecticity is *never* violated, but I'd like to find a way to obtain the error in each matrix component (the determinant is also always 1).

Comment: I was proposing to use some standard method like Dormand-Prince that is totally agnostic to any symplectic property. With the tolerances small enough the error in any structural invariants will also be small. // What second time step to use in the extrapolation depends on the method that you actually use, sometimes it might be that comparing with the $3h$ solution gives the better error estimates. The factor 2 is only automatically good for one-step methods.